# WCF access through script manager

Tags: wcf

Question: 1

I am a beginner to WCF , I have taken a web application and hosted on IIS(with some port(250) and added a new WCF file, added an operation contract and tried to call the WCF service from the client web app through javascript, i was not able to get the jsdebug file itself to check wheteher proxy is created or not.

But when i add an new AjaxEnabledWCF file and added an operation contract and tried to call the WCF service from the client web app through javascript, i was able to get the jsdebug file, i am able to get the proxy object.

In the client side i have the code like this.

.aspx

function TestWCF()
        {
          Service.DoWork(onsuccess,onError,true); 
        }

        function onsuccess(result)
        {
            alert(result);            
        }

        function onError(error)
        {
            alert("Error: " + error.message);
        }

        function onfailed(error)
        {
            var i = 'failed';            
        }

        function oncompleted()
        {
            var i = 'completed';
        }

But while invoking an operation contract i am getting 404 error and not able to figure out what is the problem

Question2 : Is there any possibility that i can make an WCF file to AjaxEnabledWCF file type

can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic check list to debug your problem:

- Check your IIS log to make sure that the request is coming in where it is supposed to.
- Check rights in IIS that the request is being allowed through.
- Check authentication / authorization in web.config.
- If impersonate is false check rights of identity of application pool
- Check security settings on disk where WCF service files are located.
- Make sure that the dll referenced in the WCF service file is in the bin directory.
- Check that ASP.net is set to 2.0 in IIS.